# Custom font drawing issue too low in label

Tags: ios, fonts, truetype, custom-font, opentype

Certain fonts draw at the upper left corner while all other are drawn vertically centered.

This can be seen in the following pictures. DCIntrospect is being used to draw the boundaries of the UILabel's view.

I'm using one font below

[image: bad font]

And I'm using the italics version here

[image: good font]

As you can see the first image has the font glued to the top edge while the other one is vertically centered.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? I've been looking into font editors but I'm not sure where to look. Some of the font editors are quite large. I've opened them both in the trial version of TypeTool and I don't see a difference in how they are placed.

I'd appreciate any help thrown my way.